# match a string followed by a number with string methods only

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

So I have written a lot of code and so far avoided importing or using regex and would prefer to keep it that way if possible.

Have a list which looks like this:

```
mylist = ["dog", "dogs", "dogs75", "75dogs", "cats75"]
```

I can get the indexes of various matched elements like this:

```
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if "cat" in j]
[4]
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if "dog" in j]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

The one I'm actually looking for is `"dogs75"`, actually any string which contains an integer at the end.

Can this be done without importing `re`?

Comment: You can check the last character with `i[-1]`, and `isalpha` or `isdigit`

Comment: @G.Anderson I think that's basically it, why was I thinking it was more than that.. If the last 1 is numeric does not really matter if the last 2 or 3 is..

Comment: I realised I actually do need `"dogs75"` only and not `"cats75"` but I can fix that by adding a `.startswith("dogs")` into the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and check if the last character of each string is numeric:

```
[ix for ix, i in enumerate(mylist) if i[-1].isnumeric()]
# [2, 4]
```

Comment: "any string which contains an integer at the end"-- your solution actually fails for facetious edge-cases like `mylist = ["dog¼"]` ;)

Comment: That's just one of it's legs ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isdecimal()` to check the last character:

```
>>> mylist = ["dog", "dogs", "dogs75", "75dogs", "cats75"]
>>> [i for i, j in enumerate(mylist) if j[-1].isdecimal()]
[2, 4]
```

You could also replace `isdecimal` with `isdigit` or `isnumeric` if you are expected number-like characters that aren't the digits 0-9

Answer (score 0):

```
[s for s in mylist if s[-1].isdigit()]
```

should give you the list you want